# Jenkins allow only members from GitHub organization to sign up via GitHub OAuth app

Tags: github, jenkins, oauth, continuous-integration, github-app

My use case seems to be really simple and clear, yet I cannot find any solution for it:
I have a Jenkins server hosted on an Azure VM. I want to allow only members of my company's GitHub organization to log in. I tried to do that by creating a GitHub OAuth app (so developers can connect using their GitHub credentials), but with this approach, everyone (not only the developers in my company) is able to create accounts into our Jenkins.
The best I could achieve so far was to forbid every operation for people outside the organization, but they are still able to create accounts.

Is there any solution for totally restricting the ability to create accounts for people that are not part of our organization? Thank you!

The GitHub OAuth app is under organization's ownership, but that does not seem to help.